# React Route sem link

Tags: react, react-router

Estou iniciando meus estudos com o React e estou usando o React Router para fazer a navegação entre as páginas clicando em links no menu, mas estou com uma duvida, como faço para acessar uma página sem um link ? Como configuro uma rota nesse caso ?!
O projeto eu criei usando o **create-react-app** e a rota que desejo configurar é **/login** para carregar a classe **Login.js**.

Código do Main.js com o menu:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Stuff from "./Stuff";
import Contact from "./Contact";


class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <HashRouter>
        <div>
        <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
        <ul className="header">
            <li><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/stuff">Stuff</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
        </ul>


        <div className="content">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
        </div>
        </div>
    </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Código do Login.js que quero configurar a rota e acessar direto pela URL:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Login extends Component {
    render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <label>
                    Name:
                <input type="text" name="name" />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro você deve importar o login no `Main.js`
**Main.js**

```
import Login from "./Login";
```

Depois ainda dentro do seu `Main.js` você deve adicionar a rota

```
<div className="content">
    // Rota login adicionada
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>

    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
</div>
```